# C++ class in Python and Python class in C++

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have the following scenario: I have some code that is in C++ and I am writing a boost wrapper around it. There is a requirement that I need to serialize the objects to be sent over a socket (in Python)

I've tried doing it directly via

- [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) (and Dill)
- [Boost python pickle](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html)

but they both lead to errors when I'm trying to deserialize it on the other end. I was then given the following to work with

```cpp
struct message_header {
  T id{};
  uint32_t size = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct message {
// Header & Body vector
  message_header<T> header{};
  std::vector<uint8_t> body;

  // Misc stuff

  friend message<T> &operator<<(message<T> &msg, const std::string &s) {
      const unsigned char *ucdata = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(s.c_str());
      // Cache the location towards the end of the vector where the pulled data starts
      size_t i = msg.body.size();
      //determine the size of the incoming data
      size_t strSize = s.size();

      // Resize the vector by the size of the data being pushed
      msg.body.resize(msg.body.size() + strSize);

      // Physically copy the data into the newly allocated vector space
      std::memcpy(msg.body.data() + i, ucdata, strSize);

      // Recalculate the message size
      msg.header.size = msg.size();

      // Return the target message so it can be "chained"
      return msg;
  }
```

where the rough idea is to

1. serialize the data as bytes within C++
2. *Pass the serialized object to Python
3. Send the serialized object to the other machine
4. *Deserialize the object (within C++)

---

I've got the code to serialize the object in C++ (which uses the code above) but I was wondering

1. how I can get that C++ object into Python (most of my boost experience is with native types),
2. how I can pass the Python-ified object back to C++ to be deserialized

Comment: You can try [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to call C++ method in python. And I think the official document of python provides some awesome examples.

Comment: What's more, please mind the memory byte order via network.

Comment: Try using a library that is designed to work across languages, like this one https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers. But there are others as well.